# working principle of top command in linux

Tags: linux, top-command

I want to understand the implementation of top command in linux ie how it uses the procfs interface for displaying the top running processes.?what sources should i refer.

Comment: The [source code](http://www.unixtop.org/) for `top` perhaps?

Comment: how do i get the source code for top?

Answer (score 3):

First, **read carefully [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)**. Then study code of [procps](https://gitorious.org/procps), and, as commented by [tangrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/268025/tangrs), of [unixtop](http://www.unixtop.org/), i.e. [top-3.7.tar.gz](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/unixtop/top-3.7.tar.gz)

For example, your program might do

```
{ FILE* psf = fopen("/proc/self/statm", "r");
  if (psf) { 
     int progsize = 0; 
     fscanf(psf, "%d", &progsize);
     printf ("program size is %d pages\n", progsize);
     fclose(psf);
  } else perror("fopen /proc/self/statm");
}
```

to print its own program size. You could make it a function:

```
int get_my_program_size(void) {
  int progsize = -1;
  FILE* psf = fopen("/proc/self/statm", "r");
  if (psf) {  
    fscanf(psf, "%d", &progsize);
    fclose(psf);
  } else perror("get_my_program_size /proc/self/statm");
  return progsize;
}
```

This is really quick: no disk i/o is involved, since the `/proc/` filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem and its file contents are computed on the fly and on demand. These pseudo-files (like `/proc/1234/statm` or `/proc/1234/status` etc....) should be read sequentially.

If you want user-mode CPU time, you could parse the 14<sup>th</sup> field (*utime*) of `/proc/self/stat` (or of `/proc/1234/stat` for the process of pid 1234). I leave that as an exercise to the reader....

Comment: how to create a simple interface in procfs for calculating running time of process

Comment: Did you *carefully* read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)? The answer is *there*

Comment: i read it but i am not getting it.Is there any other way?

Comment: No, AFAIK. And other ways probably go thru `/proc`. Did you understand what `/proc/self/status` (and `/proc/self/stat`) and `/proc/1234/status` is giving?

Comment: but how to create a interface with it?could you be more clear please

Comment: I improved my answer, but the mere fact that you asked shows that you did not read *carefully enough* the man page of `proc(5)`